# Oracle Database Design View or Table?

Tags: oracle, database-design, view

I'm new to database design and faced a problem while trying to design one. Here's my system:
There are 3 different softwares (SW_A, SW_B, SW_C) and 500-600 users. Each user can use any of  the softwares and do some work. Each work is sent to the database approx. 6 times per minute. (Randomly for users and software) 
I want a database to keep all user actions related to the softwares for archive and also want to keep track instant actions for all users related to these softwares. (Only the latest action for distinct users for each software)

So I designed sth. like that:

Table: SW_X_DATA_ARCHIVE

Columns :

- UserID
- Data_Date
- SW_A_ActionID

Table: SW_X_INSTANT_DATA

Columns:

- UserID
- Data_Date
- SW_X_ActionID

When a new data comes, it updates INSTANT_DATA table's related row if that UserID exists, inserts new row with UserID and data if not. Then inserts the same data to DATA_ARCHIVE table.

The question is: Is there a better way for this kind of work? Views maybe?
*(I've read sth. about materialized views but not sure how to use it here.)*
Thanks

Comment: The question of whether materialized views will help you or hurt you depends on what you are going to do with the data.  If almost all of your retrievals will be concerned only with the item stored in INSTANT_DATA, then your present design will probably be best.  Otherwise, you might be better off designing a single table, with a view that pulls out only the latest row for each user.  That view will not be simple to write, nor will it run blazingly fast, even with good indexing.

Comment: Thanks Walter, I used this design with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Only the latest action for distinct users for each software`

Your INSTANT table should have a unique composite key on (USERID,SOFTWAREID) so that it is not possible to have more than one row relating to a user's use of a software.

The ARCHIVE table does not require such a unique key or constraint.

You would `insert` into INSTANT if a row for (USERID, SOFTWARE) does not exist, or `update` the row if it already exists.

Typically, an insert/update trigger would be placed on the INSTANT table, to insert a row into ARCHIVE whenever a change happens to INSTANT.

EDIT: alternatively, you could maintain a single table, and have a view that selected only the latest action per user per software.  You'd need to timestamp every action and place a composite index (non-unique) on (USERID,SOFTWAREID). The decision on which approach to take might be based on relative performance.  I would tend to favor the trigger if the Latest Action information was needed frequently.

Comment: Sorry for that, I wrote SW_X_INSTANT to explain INSTANT tables exist for each Software type. SW_A_INSTANT_DATA, SW_B_INSTANT_DATA etc. So UserID will be unique for INSTANT_DATA tables.
And yes, data will directly be inserted to ARCHIVE. There's no constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. I'll also try to create a view, which will get the latest data from a Software_Archive table where UserId's are unique.. That'll be another question :)